# jackson JodaTime DateTime is not serialized

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jodatime

I am trying to start working with jackson for serializing objects having Joda `DateTime` members.

I created the following serializer:

```
public class DateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, SSS [z]");

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, 
        SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.print(value));
    }
    @Override
    public Class<DateTime> handledType() { 
        return DateTime.class; 
    }
}
```

and I am trying to serialize my class having `DateTime` members as follows:

```
    Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT");
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ZORRO", version);
    module = module.addSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer());
    // and so on...
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    mapper.writeValue(new File("C:\\tmp\\window1.json"), window1);
```

I am getting the following exception (I fail to understand what I was doing wrong):

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.joda.convert.ToString not present
at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationHelper.getAnnotation(AnnotationHelper.java:38)
at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationHelper.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationHelper.java:50)
at com.ibm.oti.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:31)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:687)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMixUnders(AnnotatedClass.java:973)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:637)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:413)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.classWithCreators(BasicClassIntrospector.java:185)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:157)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:96)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forSerialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:16)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.introspect(SerializationConfig.java:973)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:251)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:758)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:380)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:307)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:159)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:744)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2048)
```

Comment: Is joda-convert on your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the optional [joda-convert](http://joda-convert.sourceforge.net/) jar on your classpath?

BTW, is this a runtime or compile-time error?

Answer (score 0):

it's not Joda DateTime that's not serializable, it's the DateTimeFormatter.

looking at the class signature for those 2:

```
public final class DateTime
        extends BaseDateTime
        implements ReadableDateTime, Serializable {

public class DateTimeFormat {
```

now it's very clear that you should not try to serialize the formatter. but DateTime itself is perfectly fine since it implements `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Seriously?6.5 years later...))

Comment: @aviad haha, just saw this.